# Can´t add new Scalar Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my environment:

VS 2012
Asp.net MVC4

1. I created one new Model Diagram.
2. Add one Entity called Tipo
3. Right-click on model and created Database.
4. Create the controllers and views.
5. Everything working fine till now.

Now I want to add a new Scalar Property.

So, I´ve add the new Scalar Property and now I´m getting this error when I call the page:

The model backing the `TipoContext` context has changed since the database was created.

I´ve already digg the stackoverflow and found a lot of suggestion, but none worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you have added scalar property in your model, that has to be reflected in the database to work your application. For this reason, you need to enable DBMigration and let database know what changes you have made. David Hayden has nice article, have a look 
**[here](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-and-entity-framework-database-migrations).**

Comment: I tried this: 1) Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcTeste.Models.TipoContext 2) Add-Migration  TIpo  3) Update-Database. And worked fine. Now, I have to do this all the time when I chage my model?

Comment: Yes, you need to do every time, otherwise your model changes don't propagate to the database.